# Do uploaded-photos on an iPhone have a local URL?

Tags: iphone, contacts, mobile-safari

(iPhone 3GS, IOS 6.1.3).  I've uploaded a photo -say, "dog.jpg"-
to the iPhone from an iMac.  On the iPhone, I can view it using
the built-in PhotoApp [I don't know its official name].

On the iPhone: Can I access this photo via a local URL, e.g

file:///Uploaded/dog.jpg

?

More Generally:  I'm looking for a way to put several links in
a single Contacts entry.  Each, when clicked, will pull-up a local
photo [with no cell-phone service needed, no internet], either
by

- somehow directly invoking the PhotoApp on the photo, or
- by pulling up Safari using the "file://" protocol, to access the local photo.

Answer (score 2):

No, the filesystem on iOS is secured by sandboxing, so even if you had the exact path the the file - arbitrary apps could not even read the file. Of course each image is stored at some path, but it's better for apps to use the photo API to access photos than to depend on a file URL as you describe.

Comment: Ah.  So is there some other way [without an internet connection] to have multiple-photos in a Contacts-entry?  [Contacts allows you a single "photo icon".  I'm looking for multiple, e.g, husband-and-wife, then photos of them separately.]

Comment: I don't think contacts allows that. You might need to paste the photos elsewhere, store them in iPhoto or just link husband wife contacts but have each be their own entity with their own picture.